# Java file uploading using PHP : Not working

Tags: java, php, android

I'm trying to upload an image file on button click. I used the same php script for iOS and it seems to work fine. I have a added the code used to upload the file. What I suspect is that I'm not passing in the image file path correctly. I have infact added the saving image file method. I just save it as 'sign.jpeg'. I don't see the image on button click pointed to uploadfile(View view) method.

```
  public void uploadFile(View view) { 
          try {
             upload("sign.jpeg");

    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

**method implementing the file upload**

```
public void upload(String selectedPath) throws IOException {

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;

    String pathToOurFile = selectedPath;
    String urlServer = "http://localhost:8888/uploadJava.php";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                pathToOurFile));

        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream
                .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";name=\""
                        + "sign.jpeg" + "\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                + lineEnd);

        /*int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();*/
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        connection.getInputStream()));
     String inputLine;

     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);


        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

**php script to upload the file**

```
<?php
$target_path = "./images/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

 error_log("Upload File >>" . $target_path . $_FILES['error'] . " \r\n", 3,
"Log.log");

 error_log("Upload File >>" . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . " \r\n",
3, "Log.log");

 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
       echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) .
      " has been uploaded";
 } else {
     echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
 }
 ?>
```

**Saving picture taken from the camera after cropping**

```
PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {



        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 50, 200, bmp.getWidth() - 200, bmp.getHeight()/2);

        saveImage("sign.jpeg", bmp, getApplicationContext());




        try {
            FileOutputStream fos;
            fos= openFileOutput(fileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            System.out.println(data);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        finish();
        //releaseCamera();
    }

};
```

**image saving method**

```
 private void saveImage(String filename, Bitmap b, Context ctx){
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        FileOutputStream out;// = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        out = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, oos);

        oos.close();
        oos.notifyAll();
        out.notifyAll();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And yes the Internet permission is added in the AndroidManifest.xml as below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Any idea what is wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

First do this:

```
File ourFile = new File(pathToOurFile);
int ourFileLength = (int)ourFile.length();
bufferSize = Math.min(ourFileLength, maxBufferSize);
```

And then I have to admit almost never having used `available()`.
Written should be #`bytesRead`.

```
for (;;) (
    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    if (bytesRead <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

And no `notifyAll` (is for Object locks/threads).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending file to php via HTTP you might try this approach:

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("yourdomain.com");
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        try {
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
            entity.addPart("uploadedfile", new FileBody(new File ("absolute_path_to_file")));
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            String resp = client.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("log", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

For this approach you will need httpmime and httpclient lib in your build path: http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi